# JPA how to avoid updating associated entity in @ManyToOne or @OneToOne

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have two entities like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "article")
@EntityListeners({AuditingEntityListener.class})
public class Notification implements Serializable {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "notification", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST})
    private List<NotificationLang> langs;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "notification", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST})
    private List<NotificationTarget> targets;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "updated_at")
    private Date updatedAt;

    @CreatedDate
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "created_at")
    private Date createdAt;

}


@Entity
@Table(name = "article_count")
@EntityListeners({AuditingEntityListener.class})
public class NotificationTarget implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private String userId;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "notification_id")
    private Notification notification;
}
```

Notification and NotificationTarget are associated, If I update `NotificationTarget`:

```
NotificationTarget notificationTarget = notificationTargetRepository.findByNotificationIdAndUserId(
        notificationId, userId);
notificationTarget.setUserId(userId);
notificationTargetRepository.save(notificationTarget);
```

hibernate will update `Notification` too.
I have checked update Notification because Notification has EntityListener,  `AuditingEntityListener` will change `updatedAt` field when `DefaultFlushEntityEventListener` invoke Interceptor. But in this business case, I don't want to change Notification when updating NotificationTarget, is there some advice?

Sorry, I think the problem describe is wrong.

I debugged and found that update both because of `NotificationLang` list is check as dirty in `CollectionType.isEqual`. But I don't know why it is dirty??

Comment: can you explain your last paragraph a  bit more? do you never want to update the Notification in NotificationTarget? if you want to update the notification, on which cases you want to update it?

Comment: Of what the `Notifiaction` was changed?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I think always not want to update the Notification in NotificationTarget, it is just for select.

Comment: @DavePateral in my code, updatedAt field in Notificaiton is changed, because of @EntityListeners({AuditingEntityListener.class})

Comment: can you post your AuditingEntityListener class too?

Comment: @Zeromus the AuditingEntityListener class is spring jpa support. in `org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support` package.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `insertable = false, updatable = false` attributes in the mapping annotation in `NotificationTarget`

Comment: Sorry, it not works, becuase updatable meaning is: this column is included in statements or not. @anup0513

Answer (score 0):

You have added cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST} to targets in Notification class, this will propagate persistence operations to all the related entity managers.

Just remove it.

Comment: Sorry, I have tried, this not works. Because this is merge operate, not persist. @Ankur

Comment: use cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}